# How make 3 divs skew in css

Tags: html, css, skew

How to make a 3 div with distortion, as shown in the picture?

[image]

I have made this:

```css
.cars {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.car {
  width: 33.33333333%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #3498db;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: skewx(-10deg);
  -moz-transform: skewx(-10deg);
  -o-transform: skewx(-10deg);
  -ms-transform: skewx(-10deg);
  transform: skewx(-10deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}

.car:nth-child(2) {
  background: #000
}

.car:nth-child(3) {
  background: #ff0000
}
```

```html
<div class="cars">
  <div class="car"></div>
  <div class="car"></div>
  <div class="car"></div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h66q5o85/)

Left div - left corner straight, right corner slanted

Center div - left and right corner slanted

Right div - left corner slanted, right corner straight

Comment: What if you used normal 3 divs with png transparent images ?... just let them overlap each other... should do the trick

Comment: can you upload a fiddle or a sample of your whole code? including html

Comment: Every div is a link, so I need to make the blocks with distortion

Comment: Don't just inlucde a JSFiddle link, put it here too

Comment: I don't know what you mean by distortion, they're perfectly normal for me

Comment: Bálint please see picture and code)

Comment: I don't see any problem on the output, Please **describe your problem in more detail**

Comment: Please check the previous edits before you make changes. Its the second time I fixed the formatting for your. It is ok if the formatting is not well if you are new to SO, but if someone fixes that for you, then you should take care when you update your question.

Comment: The left and the central div are displayed normally, the right div should be left to the distortion, and the right to be smooth

Comment: I think they mean that the right edge of the red div should be straight, not slanted @Bálint

Comment: @Bálint you know that there might be language barriers and not everyone knows the correct terms. There is no need to be rude, by using terms like `f**k`.

Comment: Yes, right edge of the red div should be straight, not slanted

Comment: left div - left corner straight, right corner slanted
center div - left and right corner slanted
right div - left corner slanted, right corner straight

Answer (score 2):

I have used CSS's `:after` pseudo class to add another red box after the last, slanted one. However this one isn't slanted, thus 'filling in' the bit of the slant that you don't want:

```
.car:nth-child(3):after {
    /* create the box */
    content: "";
    display: block;
    /* make it fill the required space */
    width: 80%; /* (this is only 80 because it was a bit large at 100) */
    height: 100%;
    background: #ff0000;
    /* transform it in the opposite direction to counter the -10deg skew of .car */
    -webkit-transform: skewx(10deg);
    -moz-transform: skewx(10deg);
    -o-transform: skewx(10deg);
    -ms-transform: skewx(10deg);
    transform: skewx(10deg);
    transform-origin: top left;
    position: relative;
    right: -20%; /* counteract the 80% width */
}
```

I did the same with the first div, and `:before`:

```
.car:nth-child(3):before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #3498db;
    -webkit-transform: skewx(10deg);
    -moz-transform: skewx(10deg);
    -o-transform: skewx(10deg);
    -ms-transform: skewx(10deg);
    transform: skewx(10deg);
    transform-origin: top left;
    position: relative;
    right: 40%;
}
```

```css
.cars {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
.car {
  width: 33.33333333%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #3498db;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: skewx(-10deg);
  -moz-transform: skewx(-10deg);
  -o-transform: skewx(-10deg);
  -ms-transform: skewx(-10deg);
  transform: skewx(-10deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}
.car:nth-child(2) {
  background: #000;
}
.car:nth-child(3) {
  background: #ff0000;
}
.car:nth-child(3):after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ff0000;
  -webkit-transform: skewx(10deg);
  -moz-transform: skewx(10deg);
  -o-transform: skewx(10deg);
  -ms-transform: skewx(10deg);
  transform: skewx(10deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  position: relative;
  right: -30%;
}
.car:nth-child(1):before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #3498db;
  -webkit-transform: skewx(10deg);
  -moz-transform: skewx(10deg);
  -o-transform: skewx(10deg);
  -ms-transform: skewx(10deg);
  transform: skewx(10deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  position: relative;
  right: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cars">
  <div class="car first"></div>
  <div class="car"></div>
  <div class="car last"></div>
</div>
<br><br>
```